# Mobius transformation with fixed points α,β ∈ C

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Let $T$ a Mobius transformation with fixed points $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}$

Show that exist a Mobius transfotmation $S$ such as $STS^{-1}$ fix $0, \infty$, that is unique?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Questions which demand to "Show" something without anything else in the question are quite likely to be closed. You should show your own work, explain what you've tried, or explain what you do and do not understand about the question. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for tips on asking a good question, particularly [this part](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: @user10354138 my idea was to take S as a transformation that to γ maps it to 0 and β to \infty and thus build U another transformation like U = S∘T∘S ^ {- 1} then U(0)=S∘T∘S ^ {- 1}(0) =S∘T(\alpha)=S(\alpha)=0, U(\infty)=S∘T∘S ^ {- 1}(\infty)=S∘T(\infty)=S(\beta)=\infty  then U fix 0 and \infty...

Comment: @Estrellita42 That seems like a good idea. What struggle did you have?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I suppose that S exist and have the form S(z)=(z-\alpha)/(z-\beta), now I'm not sure if this is well defined and if my S is unique

Comment: @Estrellita42 Suppose $STS^{-1}$ fixes $0$ and $\infty$ and $T$ fixes $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Note $STS^{-1}$ fixes both $S(\alpha)$ and $S(\beta)$ so either $S(\alpha) = 0, S(\beta) = \infty$ or else $S(\alpha) = \infty, S(\beta) = 0$. We will refer the collection of all such solutions as $\mathcal X$...

Comment: ... Your choice of $S$ is one way to do this, but in general simply specifying the image two points does not uniquely determine a Mobius Transform and in fact there are two families of solutions for $S$ (for example, $S(z) = \tfrac{z-\alpha}{z-\beta}$ and $S(z) = \tfrac{z - \beta}{z - \alpha}$  are the simplest members of each family in $\mathcal X$ respectively).

Clearly then $S$ is not unique; perhaps the question means $U = STS^{-1}$ is independent of your choice of $S \in \mathcal X$? What is the source of this problem?